# sed expression to find a symbol followed by X numbers

Tags: bash, sed

I need help with a sed expression to find a # immediately followed by x numbers... I can't figure it out.

```
eg.

[Issue #40] or [Issue #210]
```

I need to match the `#xx` or `#xxx` pattern so I can perform a substitution on it.

Been so long since I've done any of this stuff =|

Comment: rather than adding details and other cases to comments, add a sample input and output example with different cases you need... and ideally, you need to make an effort first, https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/topics can be a simple start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to match digits immediately following a pound symbol, this should work:

```
/#[0-9]+/
```

As for the `sed` implementation or shell program implementation (e.g. `awk`), it's too hard to provide an example from your question. Here's a vague attempt...

```
sed -E 's/#[0-9]+/<replacement>/' </tmp/file.log
```

Comment: Does not seem to match at all.. running:

`sed 's/#[0-9]+/foo/' </tmp/file.log` for example... nothing gets matched or substituted in the output. The output is still exactly the same as the input.

Comment: needs `sed -r` or `sed -E` for extended regex.. or `[0-9]\+`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/#[0-9]*/foo/'
```

MIGHT be what you want but since you haven't provided anything we can test against it's a guess...

From your comments you might want:

```
sed -E 's/#[0-9]+/foo/'
```

but that might match other things you don't want to match too, idk, it all depends what the input you haven't shown us contains.

Comment: That appears to work the only issue is, it matches the symbol **'#'** when it's just by itself too... like for example in the string:

`&#x27;` it comes out `&foox27;` and this line should not even be matched.

I need it to match only if the numbers come directly after the **'#'**

Comment: It's important when you create sample input/output to include what you do NOT want to match as well as what you do want to match. Matching what you want is always trivial, it's not matching what you don't want that's always much harder. I updated my answer do tweak it to not match the things you've told us so far you don't want to match but there could be others. You really should put some effort into creating concise, testable sample input that includes all the cases you can think of that might produce false matches.